# How can I restrict the number of cpu cores available in os.cpu_count on windows (preferably via environment variable)

Tags: python, windows, python-multiprocessing

**The situation:**

I have multiple (40+) similar external applications (as in, not developed by me) written in python and delivered as windows executables. The applications use `os.cpu_count` to determine how many workers they should start. Each worker uses about 50MB of ram while idling the entire time during normal execution. I use an 8 core, 16 thread cpu. All 40+ applications start `os.cpu_count - 2` workers that do (effectively) nothing, as only one worker per application is sufficient to do the work they are supposed to do on my cpu. That makes 560 worker processes that use 27 GB of ram without any benefit.

**What I want:**

Make the applications start two workers max each, without any code change, on windows.

**What I tried:**

- Set the environment variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` globally to 4, as I could not override the environment variable in powershell for some reason. This would not be a preferable solution, as this will affect other applications as well. It did not work
- Set the cpu affinity of the main process using process hacker 2, as soon as it starts. No success.
- Set the cpu affinity while starting using `start /AFFINITY [n] [.exe]`. Still, no success. To my understanding, this one should have worked. One of the masks used was `0x000000000000000F`, the next one `0x00000000000000F0` and so on, calculated using [an online affinity mask calculator](https://bitsum.com/tools/cpu-affinity-calculator/)

Comment: 27GB of RAM or 27GB of address space? Regardless, see if [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) work for you.

Comment: @IInspectable 27GB of main memory that cannot be pooled into pagefile. "Private Working Set" in Taskmanager

Comment: This seems to be the cpp API of windows, not sure how to use that when starting an existing executable.

Comment: It's a C API. It can be called from any language that can interface with C.